# New line characters stopped getting written to PHP app's log file after switching FTP clients

Tags: php, ftp, logging

I have a website running on PHP and I fwrite a log file.   I append PHP_EOL to get each log entry on a new line.  This was working fine but about a week ago the newlines stopped appearing so the logfile is garbled.  I tried replacing PHP_EOL with \r\n but no difference.   I haven't edited the script for over a year. I'm stumped.

Comment: I very much doubt that `PHP_EOL` "stopped working" and the fact that you "tried replacing PHP_EOL with \r\n but no difference" suggests that it is indeed _something else_. What platform(s) are you using? How are you viewing these log files? Have you checked the "original" log file (before download, or transferred in binary mode) in a hex editor? My initial "guess" would be that the EOL are being "converted" during an ASCII FTP file transfer - but that's a guess.

Comment: Hum looks like it might be a problem with my ftp program.  I changed from filezilla to coffee cup freeftp about the same time.  Need to investigate further...

Comment: I'm sure you're right but "Stopped working" was the problem as I experienced it.  Using filezilla (and \r\n but that may be incidental) I'm now back in business but if it was coffeecup ftp I don't understand why the older part of the log file wasn't affected.

Comment: Yup, it's coffee cup freeftp that's the "sdomething else". and I imagine you are correct the ascii file transfer is probably the culprit.  Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem coincided with changing FTP clients (from FileZilla to "CoffeeCup Free FTP") and was possibly the result of EOL conversion during an ASCII FTP file transfer. Or even transferring in "Binary" mode from a Linux server to Windows. Typically, the FTP client will default to ASCII transfer mode for certain file types, but this is configurable within the FTP client.

In ASCII transfer mode, the EOL should never be removed completely. However, it is also dependent on the editor being used to view the resulting file and how it interprets the line endings. For example, if the EOL is the unix style `\n` then trying to display this in Windows Notepad it will all appear on one line. However, an editor like SublimeText will correctly interpret the line endings and display the file as intended.